# 'Extract-Name' error while loading AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I'm attempting to upload files into my S3 bucket, but I'm receiving this error when I call my script.

```
  Accounting::Datev::Utils::ExcelUtil.new(bucket: nil,  object_key:nil,  input_file_path: nil).call
ArgumentError: missing required option :name
from /Users/conhdss/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.9.1/lib/aws-sdk-s3/bucket.rb:666:in `extract_name'
```

I have my bucket address defined in my local.yml, so I'm unsure exactly what's being asked of me? I'll attach some more code that perhaps is relevant, I'm not sure what exactly I need to pass in, in order to get this code to work.
I've attempted to use the bucket name and file name.

```
    def initialize(bucket:, object_key:, input_file_path:)
      @bucket = bucket
      @object_key = object_key
      @input_file_path = input_file_path
    end

    def call
      # return unless input_file_path.end_with?('.xslx')
      object = s3_resource.bucket(bucket).object(object_key)
      object.upload_file(input_file_path)
    end
```